# Ayuda con array PHP

Tags: php, array

tengo un array con numeros y tengo que comprobar si estan ordenados de menor a mayor. En caso de que esten bién ordenados mostrar que estan ordenados o no en caso de no estar.
El caso es que lo tengo casi pero me da la siguiente advertencia: **Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in D:\xampp\htdocs\2ASIX\Tema4\4.php on line 12**

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php

echo "Ver si los elementos de un array estan ordenados o no</br>";

$array=array(1,2,3,6,7,8,9);
$fin=count($array);
$ordenats=array();
$desordenats=array();

for($i=0;$i<$fin;$i++){
    $num=$i+1;
    if($array[$i]<$array[$num]){
        $ordenats[$i]=$i;
    }
    else{
        $desordenats[$i]=$i;
    }   
}
if(count($desordenats)>1){
    echo "No estan ordenats";
}
else{
    echo "Estan ordenats";
}

?>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: El total de elementos de tu array es 7, pero cuando haces el if en el $i arranca por la posicion donde 0 >1, 1>2, 2>3, 3>6, 4>7, 5>8, 6>9 y cuando quiere buscar la 7 ya que pusiste que sea menor a $fin que es igual al total de elementos que hay adentro del array que es 7 no lo encuentra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Hay varias formas de hacer lo que quieres, te mostraré una muy simple:

- Guardas una copia del array sin ordenar
- Ordenas el array
- Comparas el array ordenado con la copia original: si son iguales significa que el array estaba ordenado, si no son iguales significa que no lo estaba
- Si se trata de imprimir un mensaje, puedes crear dicho mensaje desde un *operador ternario* que comparará los dos arrays.

Este es el código:

```
$array=array(1,2,3,6,8,9);
$notSorted=$array;
sort($array);
$msg=($array==$notSorted) ? "SÍ están ordenados" : "NO están ordenados";
echo $msg;
```

**Salida:**

```
SÍ están ordenados
```

Si pruebas con este array:

```
$array=array(1,2,3,6,8,4,9);
```

**Salida:**

```
NO están ordenados
```

Si quieres guardar una varible booleana de la comparación para usarla en otro sitio, puedes hacer esto:

```
$isSorted=($array==$notSorted);
```

---

#### Otra posibilidad tomando en cuenta que no te permiten usar `sort`

Yo sigo apostando por la simplicidad. En este código:

- Se crea una variable booleana establecida a `TRUE` por defecto
- Se lee cada elemento del array, guardando en `$previo` una referencia al último elemento
- Se compara si el elemento actual es `<` que el elemento previo. Si esta condición se cumple significaría que el array no está ordenado.
- Establecemos la variable booleana a `FALSE` y salimos del bucle con `break`. (Si no te permiten usar `break` haces una pequeña *trampa*, que en realidad no lo es... ¡Quitas el `break`y funcionará igual! Pero para fines de rendimiento, lo ponemos porque si esa condición se cumple una sola vez no necesitamos seguir haciendo comparaciones).
- Finalmente hacemos el `if` basándonos en el valor de `$isOrdered` ...  Ni te menciono lo de los *operadores ternarios* por ahora.

Este es el código:

```
$array=array(0,1,2,3,6,7,8);
$isOrdered=TRUE;
$previo = null;

foreach($array as $item){
    if($item<$previo){
        $isOrdered=FALSE;
        break;
    }
    $previo = $item;
}

if(!$isOrdered){
    echo "No estan ordenats";
}
else{
    echo "Estan ordenats";
}
```

Comment: Hola, he probado lo que tu me dices y funciona perfectamente, solo que como no puedo usar la funcion sort todavia pues no puedo usarlo. Aun así muchisimas gracias

Comment: @ElvillanodePHP ¿no la puedes usar porque es un ejercicio de un curso o algo así?

Comment: Efectivamente, es un ejercicio de clase y de momento no nos dejan usar funciones así. Y como llevo desde el miercoles dandole vueltas muchos cerebros funcionan mejor que uno. :)

Comment: @ElvillanodePHP sigo apostando por la simplicidad. He adjuntado al final de la respuesta una posibilidad sin tener que usar `sort`, ni ternarios.

Comment: Pues la verdad es que asi es mas simple que de el modo que estaba intentandolo yo. Muchisimas gracias por tu aportación.

Answer (score 0):

el error pasa cuando llega al final del elemento y suma uno y el indice queda como 7
y como el array solo tiene hasta el indice 6 te da error, lo que podrias hacer es validar que sume solo cuando este  sea menor que el tamaño del array -1 asi

```
<?php
echo "Ver si los elementos de un array estan ordenados o no</br>";

$array=array(1,2,3,6,7,8,0);
$fin=count($array);
$ordenats=array();
$desordenats=array();

for($i=0;$i<$fin;$i++){
  if($i<$fin-1)$num=$i+1;

  if($array[$i]<$array[$num]){
    $ordenats[$i]=$i;
  }
  else{
     $desordenats[$i]=$i;
  }
}

if(count($desordenats)>1){
   echo "No estan ordenats";
}
else{
   echo "Estan ordenats";
}

?>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciona perfectamente.